# Click does not work on iPad when pressed for too long

Tags: html, angular, ipad, web-applications, user-experience

I have developed a webapp which we usually run on an ipads browser, usually Chrome. There is a problem for a older users when they need to press on a button. They usually press hard and longer than average users, thus the click never gets registered.

The app is an angular app and I've tried to bind a (mousedown) event in hopes of making it fire the event when first touch it. But it seems like that when you hold it down longer on an ipad, it just starts to focus on the text.

Any ideas on how to improve the UX in this case? A lot of older users gets frustrated because to them it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hold your finger on the button you may never reach the mouse events, especially if you move your finger a little. You may check the order of events here https://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/tests/event-listener_all-no-timings.html
To handle your issue you may handle either pointerdown or touchstart event.